# How to convert a List<String> to Map<String, Long> using Lambda, where the key is the String and the value is a count of the number of vowels?

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-stream, collectors

Given:

```
List<String> myStrings = Arrays.asList("broom", "monsoon");
```

Return:

```
Map<String, Long> stringToNumberOfVowels = Map.of("broom", 2, "monsoon", 3);
```

This is what i've tried:

```
Map<String, Long> vowelsMap = Stream.of("broom").flatMapToInt(String::chars).filter("aeiou".indexOf(c) >= 0).mapToObj(c -> "aeiou".indexOf(c)>=0 ? "broom" : "").collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.indenty(), Collectors.counting()));

for(Map.Entry<String, Long> a : vowelsMap.entrySet()) { System.out.println(a.getKey() + "==>"); System.out.println(a.getValue()); }
```

My Output (which only works with 1 string being passed in the stream):

broom ==> 2

Desired Output:

broom ==> 2

monsoon ==> 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is a little bit complicted, a simple way is to use stream collect with [`Collectors::toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) like this:

```
Map<String, Long> vowelsMap = myStrings.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                str -> str.chars().filter(c -> "aeiou".indexOf(c) >= 0).count()));
```

Comment: Or even `str -> str.replaceAll("[^aeiou]+", "").length()`

Comment: Using a regex where a simple loop or stream is just as easy and readable is like using a sledgehammer to hang a painting. It may work, but I would not call it the right tool for the job. I find the provided answer cleaner, and it probably outperforms the regex parsing, matching and replacing.